# sensor_msgs.msg Image type value error. "Not a message data class"

Tags: ros, sensor-msgs, ros-kinetic, image, sensor-msgs#image

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm getting a value error when trying to run this code:

```
front_image_pub = rospy.Publisher('/front_camera/image_raw', Image, queue_size=10)
```

The precise error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/nrgadmin/catkin_ws/src/vr_ui/src/playback.py", line 80, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/nrgadmin/catkin_ws/src/vr_ui/src/playback.py", line 67, in main
    front_image_pub = rospy.Publisher('/front_camera/image_raw', Image, queue_size=10) 
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/topics.py", line 842, in __init__
    super(Publisher, self).__init__(name, data_class, Registration.PUB)
  File "/opt/ros/kinetic/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/rospy/topics.py", line 144, in __init__
    raise ValueError("data_class [%s] is not a message data class"%data_class.__class__.__name__)
ValueError: data_class [type] is not a message data class
```

So the fun thing about this error, is that when I substitue the Image type with any of the other sensor_msgs.msg types (such as Temperature, CompressedImage, or Joy) I don't have any error at all.

Here's a link to the full code: https://github.com/SouLeo/360_lab_visualization/blob/master/src/playback.py

My package.xml is here: https://github.com/SouLeo/360_lab_visualization/blob/master/package.xml

My CMakeList is here: https://github.com/SouLeo/360_lab_visualization/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt

I'm so sorry for being dumb, but I seriously don't understand why some sensor_msg topics work and then Image doesn't.

Other things I have tried include:

1. Clean building my vr_ui package
2. verifying my package.xml and cmake list included sensor_msgs.msg dependency

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/292879/sensor_msgs.msg-image-type-value-error.-%22not-a-message-data-class%22/) by [SouLeo](https://answers.ros.org/users/35604/souleo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 35 on 2018-05-31

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like you have a name collision between your class named `Image` and the message type you are importing as `Image`.

Can you try importing the Image message with a different name? e.g.

`from sensor_msgs.msg import Image as ImageMsg`

And use `ImageMsg` to create your publisher

`front_image_pub = rospy.Publisher('/front_camera/image_raw', ImageMsg, queue_size=10)`

Alternative: Or you can try renaming your `Image` class to something like `MyImage`

---

Originally posted by [marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/) with karma: 3606 on 2018-05-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [SouLeo](https://answers.ros.org/users/35604/souleo/) on 2018-05-31**:
This is brilliant, and I can’t believe I didnt catch this. Thank you so so much!!

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-05-31**:
This is definitely the culprit. One needs to be careful with name collisions.

**Comment by [marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/) on 2018-05-31**:
@SouLeo can you please accept the answer (tick the box) if this solved your issue.
This will let people know that the answer has been accepted and that the problem doesn't need further investigation. Thanks!

**Comment by [SouLeo](https://answers.ros.org/users/35604/souleo/) on 2018-05-31**:
done! (I think)